# Multiple listeners in one class

Tags: android, interface, listener

I guess everybody knows the listener interface pattern. I have a class with some favorite items the user can add or remove.

In this class I have:

```
public static OnFavsChangedListener onFavsChangedListener; 

public interface OnFavsChangedListener {
    abstract void onFavsChanged();
}

public static void setOnFavsChangedListener(
        OnFavsChangedListener listener) {
    onFavsChangedListener = listener;
}

public void addToFavorites () {
    if (onFavsChangedListener != null) {
        onFavsChangedListener.onFavsChanged()
    }
}
```

This works great when I only need to use ONE of those listeners, when I use `setOnFavsChangedListener` from different `Activities`, they will overwrite the last one.

My idea was to use an `ArrayList` of listeners and call them all when my Favs change, but it's hard to not let the `ArrayList` grow too big (`Activities` might add a listener on every orientation change / `onCreate`). I could use a `HashMap` of IDs and listeners, let every `Activit`y remove it's listener `onDestroy`, but that seems clumsy.

TL;DR: Whats an elegant way for several `Activities` to be informed when my Favs change?

Comment: What is managing the "Favs"? IOW, who would be calling `addToFavorites()` in your scenario?

Comment: I was going to suggest what bclymer has stated in his answer, use a Bus to iron that out. If you don't want to do that though, the typical pattern IS to use a Collection of listeners, and listeners need to unregister themselves when done (this is a common cause of bugs/leaks, but that's how it generally works, and that's one of the reasons the bus is preferred -- also bus is a lot less code).

Comment: @CommonsWare addTofavorites might be called from different Activities too. It's a public static method. I have taken care of possible ConcurrentModificationExceptions though.

Comment: Yeah, I'd echo the recommendation on using an event bus. I haven't used greenrobot's EventBus, though I have used Square's Otto with success. You still should proactively unregister from the bus, though, whether in `onDestroy()` or another lifecycle method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be overkill for your use case, but for notifying classes about events I use an event bus (specifically https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

This allows you to simply post a message and every class that has registered to receive that type of message gets it. Very simple to use, and pretty small as far as libraries go.

Comment: I'll definitely have a look at that, because I only posted a simplified version, in fact I have different lists of Favorites, Items to order etc. so this might save me some trouble in the long run. Thanks for the proposition.

Comment: I'm glad you like it, I'm quite the fan of it myself.